# Can I use Travis environment variables in a Podfile?

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci

I have a Podfile which has the following:

```
if ENV['TRAVIS']
  # Load pod from GitHub
else
  # Load pod from local path
end
```

This used to work but apparently no longer does since my builds are erroring because the `TRAVIS` environment variable isn't evaluating as `true`.

Can I still use Travis environment variables in a Podfile?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've added some links to the `before_install` phase of my travis config to `echo $TRAVIS` and `echo $CI`, but they both appear to be blank. Other environment variables I have manually set print out the expected values.

Comment: It has occurred to me that since the environment variables that I have manually set appear to be working, that I could just use one of those instead. I'd still like to understand what's going on here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the environment variables are missing on Mac VMs and are being tracked by [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1764).